# Run script in a screen

Tags: shell-script, scripting, gnu-screen, shebang

I want to run a bash script in a detached screen. The script calls a program a few times, each of which takes too long to wait. My first thought was to simply open a screen and then call the script, but it appears that I can't detach (by `ctrl-a d`) while the script is running. So I did some research and found this [instruction](http://www.kormoc.com/2013/06/19/force-a-bash-script-to-run-in-screen/) to replace the shebang with following:

```
#!/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S screenName /bin/bash
```

But that doesn't work, either (the options are not recognized). Any suggestions?

PS It occurs to me just now that `screen -dmS name ./script.sh` would probably work for my purposes, but I'm still curious about how to incorporate this into the script. Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line you've seen may work on some unix variants, but not on Linux. Linux's shebang lines are limited: you can only have one option. The whole string `-d -m -S screenName /bin/bash` is passed as a single option to `screen`, instead of being passed as different words.

If you want to run a script inside screen and not mess around with multiple files or quoting, you can make the script a shell script which invokes screen if not already inside screen.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then exec screen -dm -S screenName /bin/bash "$0"; fi
do_stuff
more_stuff
```

Comment: It works well, what is the `"$0"` for here ?

Comment: @Lordofdark That's the script name. The script invokes `screen` which invokes `/bin/bash` which invokes the script again.

Answer (score 23):

According to the screen man pages:

- `screen -d -m`
     Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.
- `-S sessionname`
     Set the name of the new session to sessionname.

So when I ran the command you provided: `screen -dmS name ./script.sh`

Screen starts a window called name and automatically runs that script.sh. To get back into there to see the status you would simply type: `screen -r test`

Now with Ubuntu 14.04, the commands are slightly different. Try:

`screen -d -m -S test`

Now for running the script, you will need to go to their config file to do so:

`sudo vim /etc/screenrc`

Once there, scroll down to the bottom and you will see:

```
# Example of automatically running some programs in windows on screen startup.
#
#   The following will open top in the first window, an ssh session to monkey
#   in the next window, and then open mutt and tail in windows 8 and 9
#   respectively.
#
# screen top
# screen -t monkey ssh monkey
# screen -t mail 8 mutt
# screen -t daemon 9 tail -f /var/log/daemon.log
```

This is the section where you will need to add the script name to run and that should allow you to do everything you needed from screen.

Comment: Somehow that command (`screen -dmS ...`) doesn't work for me, even though it really should. I run it and then `screen -ls` and no sockets are found. Thoughts?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr" I think. It's a virtual machine.

Comment: Gimme a bit because im just leaving work and ill try to use screen on my machine which is also ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @bongbang - what version of screen do you have?

Comment: @slm Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU). The help shows the `dmS` option, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for effort, but I still don't quite get it. Am I supposed to uncomment the excerpted part of screenrc?

Comment: @bongbang Screen may be starting and finishing before you run 'screen -ls'. Try running something like 'sleep 60' in the bash script so you have 60 seconds to either 'screen -ls' or 'ps -uf' to see it.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit old but one of the few threads I could find to do this. After toying arount the only way to get this running in detached mode with ubuntu 14. is

```
screen -d -m -t nameofwindow sh nameoflaunch.sh
```

The launch would be the second part above that houses the current java commands and server version. I run vanilla.