# Join an interactive session of a process launched from rc.local

Tags: process, shutdown, reboot, stdin, rc

Is there a way to join an interactive session of a process that was ran on boot with /etc/rc.local, or send it "stop" over STDIN on reboot/shutdown and wait for it to end before shutting down?

Comment: If you launch it in something like `screen` or `tmux` you could certainly do that

Comment: @EricRenouf even if launched at startup? And is there a way to automate the process with, as I said, sending stop to the process over STDIN and wait for it to end before shutting down (I do need the network interface to be still up before the process ends).

Comment: Sure, you can script starting a process inside screen see some examples [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162133/run-script-in-a-screen) and you can send commands later to it like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen)

Comment: @EricRenouf But doesn't that have to be from the same session?

Comment: Nope, that's the advantage of using something like `screen` or `tmux`, they'll have their own psuedo-tty that you can attach to any time you like, and detach from again and they'll keep going.  They're really useful if you're going to want something to continue across sessions in particular.  I use it to start some jobs then ssh from another machine to see how they're going for example

Comment: @EricRenouf and what about that waiting for the process to die?

Comment: `rc.local` has been superseded on many operating systems, several times over on some.  It only thus works at all via backwards compatibility shims.  Exactly how those backwards compatibility shims work varies, moreover.  With several of them `rc.local` _does not even have_ an interactive session and a controlling terminal.  `rc.local` thus does not work the same everywhere, and you need to be specific about what operating system this question pertains to.

Comment: As JdeBP points out, there's probably actually a better way to go (like making a systemd unit that will handle starting and stopping).  If you want to do it manually though, you could find the PID of the process and then use `wait` after you send it the stop, or keep checking with `pgrep` or similar

Comment: @JdeBP in my case it's run by rc.local script inside /etc/init.d on boot - Ubuntu

Comment: Related: [How to recover a backgrounded job from a previous shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49106/how-to-recover-a-backgrounded-job-from-a-previous-shell)

Comment: Even that is not specific enough, as you could be using either Upstart or systemd, and the backwards compatibility shims for `rc.local` are different in each.  You really do need to be _specific_.  In the wider picture, you should of course [forget about `rc.local`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333003/5132).

Comment: Well, it looks like latest LTS Ubuntu (not sure why wouldn't you run the latest LTS version honestly) uses systemd... @JdeBP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been explained in comments, you need to “save” the process's stdin somehow. By default, depending on the init system, this may be the console, or `/dev/null`. To be able to attach to the process, use a screen multiplexer such as [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). See also [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

In `/etc/rc.local`, run something like

```
screen -S mydaemon -md /usr/local/bin/mydaemon --some-option
```

To attach to the program interactively, you would then run

```
screen -S mydaemon -rd
```

To automatically send keystrokes to the program (see [sending text input to a detached screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen)):

```
screen -S mydaemon -p 0 -X stuff 'bye^M'
```

Comment: What's up with the "stuff" in the last one?

Comment: @JanNovák That sends keyboard input to the application, which you requested in the question.