# How to spawn a user screen in a docker container?

Tags: bash, debian, gnu-screen, monitoring

[runsvdir: UNIX **init scheme** with service supervision](http://smarden.org/runit/) from `runit` is a nice tool to re-run some service(s) if it dies. It monitor a directory for changes, `inotify` like. It execute scripts in directories forever.

I have a structure like this:

```
$ tree app
app
├── service
│   ├── run
│   └── supervise
├── replay
│   ├── run
│   └── supervise
└── run
    ├── run
    └── supervise
```

What I would like to do is something like this, based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162133/run-script-in-a-screen) in `app/run/run` and `app/replay/run` (I tried the solution in the link, but it fails):

```
su - user -c screen -S run<<EOF
[...]
# code
EOF
```

The code have to block/wait to avoid `runsvdir` to run multiple instances in //.

The code is run as root in a `docker` container. No `systemd` there.

I tested many solutions, have defuncts pids, of multiple processes in // that I want to avoid. I miss something maybe obvious.

Any idea?

- debian 11 until next week ;)
- runit 2.1.2-41

**Note/Edit**: it's not mandatory to create run/replay from `init`. It can be a shell script (bash). The `screen`'s have to be run only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed like this after `docker build .`:

```
docker exec -d -u mevatlave cont screen -d -m -S run ./run
docker exec -d -u mevatlave cont screen -d -m -S replay ./replay.sh
docker exec -it -u mevatlave cont screen -x run
```